# plotKML: plot image stored locally not on WikiMedia

Tags: r, plot, kml

How can I plot a image saved locally with `plotKML::spPhoto()`?

Using *T. Hengl's* **Field photographs** example, I get an error when I point to the same photo saved locally.  I replaced `x1$url$url` with the local path to the same image.

```
imagename = "Soil_monolith.jpg"
x1 <- getWikiMedia.ImageInfo(imagename)
# sm <- spPhoto(filename = x1$url$url, exif.info = x1$metadata) 
local <- "C:/Users/user1/Desktop/Soil_monolith.jpg"
sm <- spPhoto(filename = local, exif.info = x1$metadata)
```

Returns

```
Error in spPhoto(filename = local, exif.info = x1$metadata) : 
  File C:/Users/user1/Desktop/Soil_monolith.jpg could not be located.
```

However, `shell.exec(local)` opens the photo with no problem, so I know the path is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out:

The `spPhoto()` function needs a browser friendly url path.  So, the problem was solved with:

```
 local <- "file:///C:/Users/user1/Desktop/Soil_monolith.jpg"
```